# CSS: как объединить несколько nth-of-type в один?

Tags: html, css, nth-of-type

Сейчас на сайте работает следующая конструкция:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div:nth-of-type(4),
div:nth-of-type(7),
div:nth-of-type(10),
div:nth-of-type(13),
div:nth-of-type(16),
div:nth-of-type(19) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Как прописать селектор, который бы объединял все эти nth-of-type? (т.е. начиная с 4-го далее каждый 3-й).

Comment: :nth-child(3n + 4)

Comment: @МузыкаСергей надо ж было ответом оформить

Comment: надеюсь я помог, и моего комментария достаточно ;)

Comment: @МузыкаСергей, да, за помощь спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Всё очень просто...

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
div:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(3n+1)
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Плюс поставил, но вариант :nth-child(3n + 4) мне кажется проще и изящнее.